# scrollview is not working in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am having root layout and i placed background image to that linear layout.I placed scroll view inside linear layout.I want content on the bottom of the screen and i need scroll view also.But my content is always getting up on the screen,unable to get bottom of the screen,I applied weight in scroll view but weight is applied in scroll view but scrollview not working.what to do to work scrollview.Thanks in advance.
I am trying below code here.

## MyActivity.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.6"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="15dp" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/roundcorneredittextwithskycolor"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:hint="@string/medicaid"
                                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/app_font" >

                                <requestFocus />
                            </EditText>

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/roundcorneredittextwithskycolor"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:hint="@string/password"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/app_font" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/forgotpwd"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/forgotpassword"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="|"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/createaccount"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/createaccount"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/dropshadow"
                            android:text="@string/signin"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                            android:text="@string/copyright"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: But content is getting up,i want content on the bottom of the screen.i applied gravity botttom.but not getting content on bottom

Comment: May be I'm not getting you properly. Content is getting up?

Comment: yes,content is getting up.I want bottom of the screen

Comment: you cn give all LinearLayout `android:height="wrap_content"`